# if we want to use bootstrap and tailwind css together

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, bootstrap-5

I'm currently developing my portfolio using React.js and have created multiple components, including About, Contact, and Education. I'm using both Bootstrap and Tailwind CSS for designing.

For example, I've applied Bootstrap classes to the About and Contact components. However, I want to apply Tailwind CSS classes specifically to the Education component.

How can I achieve this?

I've attempted to apply Tailwind CSS classes directly to the Education component by adding Tailwind-specific class names to the HTML elements within the Education component's JSX code. However, when I view the component in the browser, it doesn't seem to be applying the Tailwind styles as expected. Instead, it appears to be using the Bootstrap styles. I expected the Education component to display with the Tailwind CSS styles applied, while the About and Contact components continue to use Bootstrap styles

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: try not to use both togather for example tailwind and bootstrab have a container class 
so the values are gonna override and its not fun